# Counting line number of a huge folder failed in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Update:
The folder size is 2T!!! Now my question is how to handle such a large file with Spark?

---

I have a online storage with a huge folder size (at least 200 GB, I do not know the exact size). 
I am counting the line number of all files inside the huge folder.

```
spark.sparkContext.textFile("online/path").filter(x => x.contains("keyword")).count
```

But it always failed. I checked the Spark UI which shows total task number is 1,546,000 and my program fails after around finishing 110,000 tasks.

I tried to check the log file but the log file itself is huge and got stuck being read into my browser.

I also tried mapParititions:

```
spark.sparkContext.textFile.mapPartitions(p => p.filter(x => x.contains("keyword"))).count()
```

No luck.

My config:

```
Driver Memory: 16G
Executor memory: 16G
Executor Number: 12
Executor Core number :10
```

My spark cluster has 138 cores and 800G memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each task assigned to a ~128MB partition, and 10 cores per executor, I would expect this job to complete on your cluster. It may be the case that you have too many tasks, as each tasks comes with non-trivial overhead.  To test this hypothesis try reducing the number of partitions with coalesce. e.g.:

```
spark.sparkContext.textFile("online/path").coalesce(1000).filter(x => x.contains("keyword")).count
```

Comment: The issue is not it takes too much time. Instead, the issue is it crashed.

Comment: I used repartition:     repartition(120) and still the same.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.  The overhead of 1.5 million tasks is likely causing the crash.  I can replicate the issue on a small cluster with the following: val df = (0 until 1500000).toDF.repartition(1500000);
df.count;  repartitioning is different from coalesce in that, a coalesce(1000) will not cause a shuffle and trigger 1.5 million tasks, while a repartition(1000) will still trigger the 1.5 million tasks as it shuffles data around.

Comment: "textFile" has second parameter - "minPartitions", maybe, you can try it.
Also what is the crash error? Also if files size is small, and file count is huge, other read method can be used "wholeTextFiles"

Answer (score 0):

"textFile" has second parameter - "minPartitions", maybe, you can try it.

If files size is small, and file count is huge, other read method can be used "wholeTextFiles"